# How to get attendees list of a meeting call in MSTeams?

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

I need to get list of attendees of a MSTeams meeting call, and their times by an Azure Application.

For now, i've tried 3 different approaches without success:

- Registering a Bot
- Retrieve the attendee report of an event
- callRecord subscription

In more detail:

**Registering a Bot**

MembersAdded event works as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/subscribe-to-conversation-events?tabs=dotnet#team-members-added) for v4.7 of the Bots SDK, ie. when a new user is added to a chat or a team, webhook is called, which does not work for online meetings. However for v3 of the [Bots SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notifications#team-member-or-bot-addition) there is a mention:

> The conversationUpdate event with the membersAdded object in the
> payload is sent when a user is added to a private scheduled meeting.
> The event details will be sent even when anonymous users join the
> meeting.

I've not tried this version of SDK, but i think it has the same behaviour as v4.7 because i don't see any  request comming to my bot's webhook when an user joins a meeting.

Moreover, when i request Members of a meeting on message event to a bot by invoking:

```
var members = await TeamsInfo.GetMembersAsync(turnContext);
```

i get a list of team/chat members where a meeting is created but not the list of attendees of a meeting for the current time.

**Retrieve the attendee report of an event**

[By this request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-beta&preserve-view=true&tabs=http#example-4-retrieve-the-attendee-report-of-a-live-event), I can get the list of attenees, but only for live events.
However Teams clients (in preview mode now) can get this report for ordinary meeting with the full history of who/when entered/leaved a meeting with even guest names(!).
Anyway, this method has the following disadvantages:

- As mentioned in the [Get onlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-beta&preserve-view=true&tabs=http#example-4-retrieve-the-attendee-report-of-a-live-event) and according to the [Allow applications to access online meetings on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy), a Tenant administrator have to invoke PS command *Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy* for each meeting organiser, to grand my app permision to download this report

> Administrators must create an application access policy and grant it to a user, authorizing the
> app configured in the policy to retrieve an
> online meeting on behalf of that user (user ID specified in the
> request path).

- Uses Beta version of the GraphAPI, so it can't be used in production

**callRecord subscription**

According to the [Create subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), i can subscribe to create and update events of a callRecord, and everything works well - when a meeting call is finished, my notification URL is called in 5-20 minutes, so i can find original meeting by callRecord.joinWebUrl and [Get onlineMeeting:Example 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-beta&preserve-view=true&tabs=http). Seems it's most suitable method for me, but has the following disadvantages:

- Guests cannot be identified, their names as them passed in MSTeams clients are not reported to callRecord ie. callRecord.Participants[].AddtionalData["guest"].displayName == "Guest user" for any guest (seems like a bug), however entered/leaved information can be found by searching callRecord.Participants[].AddtionalData["guest"].id in callRecord.Sessions[].Segments[].Caller.Identity.AddtionalData["guest"].id
- External users cannot be also indentified, callRecord.Participants[].User.DisplayName == "External user" for any external user, however i can retrive tenantId and userId, but still cannot get user's profile because my app has to have Directory.Read.All permision in that tenant, and it's not possible for every tenant.

PS. I can setup MSTeams to do not allow guests or external users, then it works partially well, because each user has to have Teams license assigned, and there is **NO** login page appears during joining a meeting, just an error page saying that meeting does not allow guest or external users, so the user should find a link to login to a tenant, which is not obvious in MSTeams Web Client, but possible.

PSS. In the Microsoft Teams admin center, i've checked the calling history of an organiser for a meeting with 1 guest, 1 tenant and 1 external and here it is:

[image: Calling history]

Seems for guests, displayName is not stored at all, however for an external user there AAD email is stored (this is AAD guest user ie has '#EXT#' in his principal name, and has the same email as on the picture), however i'm not sure from where it resolved from by Azure - either from external tenant AAD or my tenant AAD for external user, because Azure has access to both.

---

So, maybe you know a method to get attendees and their times in a meeting call ?

Thank you for your suggestion/advice/reply !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching us!

Teams by default generate attendees report and meeting report after completion of meeting call. We can able to see the list of attendees and the report. But at present we don't have any API to fetch list of attendees and their timings.

As this feature is not available at present, could you please raise an [UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new) if this needs to be consider as a future request.

Comment: Well, thanks for explanation, but is there any way for app on behalf of an organiser get this report ? CSV/JSON not matter. MSTeams does it somehow from backend, and this API seems internal